# Comparing two GPS tracks for similarity

Tags: geometry, hausdorff-measure

I am a software developer not a mathematician, so going easy on me would be greatly appreciated.

I need a way of comparing various methods of determining location against a known route.  This will take the form of tracks, i.e., arrays of lat-longs. I need to write some code that will compare the two arrays and give me a measure of how similar they are to one another.

I have computed the sum and the average cross track error by cycling through each point and measuring the distance to the closest point of the known route, but I am not sure whether it tells me anything useful.

I have seen some articles on Hausdorff distance (and dimension) and in particular Wikipedia describes *"A measure for the dissimilarity of two shapes is given by Hausdorff distance up to isometry"*, which looks promising but I confess I don't understand what this means let alone how to implement the algorithm in code.

In short I would like to be able to quantify that method 1 is better than method 2 at determining location and any help would be useful.

Comment: So the ground truth is an array of lat-long pairs that you have and that you know to be accurate? How many lat-long pairs are there in the ground truth array?

Comment: Yes and could be anywhere between 30 - 100 points. The track to compare against the ground truth could contain approximately 2000 points.

Comment: Thanks. So we can visualize a track just by plotting all the points that belong to the track, and connecting the dots. If you visualize a few different tracks that way, is it usually pretty clear which track agrees most closely with the ground truth?

Comment: You could imagine two cars, each traversing its own track at a constant rate of speed, and taking the time average of the distance between the 2 notional cars.  To do this involves a kind of track dependent time-warping which requires a side calculation.  Which might be thrown off by a few wildly inaccurate points.